# get information from JSON data in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

How to get information from **JSON**.
I am using **AJAX** to get **JSON** and then parsing returned **JSON** to **HTML**.

**Values are not fix in JSON Output.so i cant use hard code.**

**Updated : How to Parse this JSON**

```
[{"4":"YS"},{"5":"YM"},{"6":"YL"}]
```

To parse this i am using

```
$.each( resType, function( i, val ) {
    $("#Type").append(val[0]);   //not getting anything here
});
```

**Previous Question:**

nothing Getting in **HTML** when trying to Parse using  `$("#Type").val(resultType[0]);`

**Console OutPut of JSON**

```
{"1":"Youth"}
```

**AJAX**

```
$.ajax({
type: "post",
dataType: "json",
url: urlToGetType,
data: dataType,
success: function (resultType, status) {
 $("#Type").val(resultType[0]);   //Nothing Getting here
},
error: function (xhr, desc, err) {

}
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="Type" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" value="" />
```

Comment: try using `resultType['1']`

Comment: resultType doesn't look like it'd be an array and I don't know what element #Type is but try resultType["1"] instead

Comment: Are you saying that the result is with an object with a single property/value pair, that you won't know what the property name will be, but you want to use the value regardless?

Comment: Thankx to DownVote. Here on SO it iss becoming a Fun to give Downvote. :)

Comment: I don't understand - you are trying to set the value of an input to a JS object. That shouldn't work. Are you asking how to get the value of an object that is only going to have a single value, e.g., `{"1":"Youth"}`?

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the value incorrectly:

Try this:

```
$("#Type").val(resultType["1"]);
```

Comment: if you format your JSON this way: [{"1":"Youth"}] then accessing resultType[0] will return the object.

Comment: but my values are not fix

Comment: you are trying to read the object like an array. Your JSON is not formatted properly.

Answer (score 0):

***This depends on the dataType parameter.***

jQuery's ajax does some interpreting of the first parameter of the success function:

```
...The data returned from the server, formatted according to the dataType parameter;
```

If dataType is "json" then you resultType will be an object and you can access the value with:

```
resultType['1']
```

If dataType is (basically) anything else, then resultType will be a string and you cannot access the data inside of the JSON string without evalulating it.